# Take in-app photo with Cordova Camera and upload it to Parse.com

Tags: angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building an Ionic/Cordova app which uses Parse.com as a BaaS. It uses the ngCordova Camera plugin to control the device camera. The use-case is click a button, take a picture and have it upload to Parse. I've been researching the problem for a week now and still can't figure out why I can't get it to work.

**The controller:**

```
.controller('cameraCtrl', function($scope, camera) {

var cameraOptions = {
quality: 75,
destinationType: 0,
encodingType: 0,
targetWidth: 300,
targetHeight: 300,
mediaType: 0,
correctOrientation: true,
saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};
    };

    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        cameraOptions.sourceType = 1;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, cameraOptions);
    }

    $scope.selectPicture = function() {
        cameraOptions.sourceType = 0;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, cameraOptions);
    }

    function onSuccess(picture) {

        File.upload(picture)
            .success(function(data) {
                // upload finish
            });

        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.preview = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + picture;
        });
    }

    function onFail(resp) {
        alert('Error: ' + resp);
    }

});
```

**The service:**

```
angular.factory('File', function ($http) {
return {
    upload: function (photo) {

        var json = {
            'base64': photo,
            '_ContentType': 'image/jpeg'
        }

        var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/pict.jpg',
            data: json,
            headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'PCm0kDVeThvRcdFuS9lITrmskEhqjbqwFAydL2Lr',
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'FhasGkTl0BLpJuLLJvPB2NFwlccXzVbirktdngXN'
            }
        };

        return $http(config);
    }
}
});
```

**The HTML:**

```
<button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">
```

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work? Is there a better or more simple way to accomplish this? Any examples of this working somewhere? I've tried a dozen different solutions over the week and haven't found anything that works for my use-case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful is you provided any error messages, but here is how I have solved the issue

```
        var imageFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {base64: _params.photo});
        console.log(imageFile);

        // save the parse file
        return imageFile.save().then(function () {

            // create object to hold caption and file reference
            var imageObject = new ImageObject();

            // set object properties
            imageObject.set("caption", _params.caption);
            imageObject.set("picture", imageFile);

            // save object to parse backend
            return imageObject.save();


        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(error);
        });
```

There is a complete project here showing Parse.com integration with the File Object.

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/dcww/blob/master/www/js/services.js

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for replying! I came across your app in my research, and honestly I have a hard time separating out the code needed for just for the photo+upload actions from the other services integrated with it (the map and friends aspects.) I've only been working with Cordova for about a month, so I'm still pretty new to this. Would you be able to provide any more guidance on which parts of the DCWW app I'd need to pluck out in order to get the "take photo + upload to Parse" flow going? Even line numbers would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add a issue to  the github repo on the project and I will take a look. We can manage the discussion there as opposed to the SO thread